# How to create Multipolygon from Polygons table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have polygon table "PARCELA" with geometry column "GEOMETRY". How I can create multipolygon from these polygons?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired o/p?

Comment: I have just table with gemetry column named "GEOMETRY" it can be any table with polygons. I just need to create Multipolygon from Polygons in table.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but:
If you have polygon A and polygon B and you want to combine them as one polygon here is what I have used.
What I needed was to get nordic countries together so I could print them on a map as one.

I have table countries with geometry column "geom" and column "ISO3" where country codes are located. So I am using ISO3 column as my primary key.

```
DECLARE @gtbl TABLE(g geometry, id INT)
INSERT INTO @gtbl 
SELECT null,1

DECLARE @t TABLE(PK INT Identity(1,1), ISO3 VARCHAR(3))

INSERT INTO @t
Select ISO3 From countries WHERE ISO3 in ('FIN','SWE','NOR','DNK')

Declare @maxPK int; Select @maxPK = MAX(PK) From @t
Declare @pk int; Set @pk = 1

While @pk <= @maxPK

Begin

    IF ((SELECT g FROM @gtbl) IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE gtbl SET g = c.Geom.MakeValid()
            FROM @gtbl gtbl, countries c WHERE  c.ISO3 in (Select ISO3 From @T Where PK = @pk)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE gtbl SET g = g.STUnion(c.Geom.MakeValid())
            FROM @gtbl gtbl, countries c
            WHERE  c.ISO3 in (Select ISO3 From @T Where PK = @pk)
        END

    Select @pk = @pk + 1
End


SELECT * FROM @gtbl
```